# How to traverse a b-tree to see if its a valid b-tree

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, b-tree

Whats the best way to traverse a b-tree so i can confirm that the nodes are in order.  I believe that for b-tree

The golden rule for a b-tree is:
For each key k in the tree -  all the left children  must have keys less than k, and all children to the right must have keys greater than k.

so imagine i had a b-tree that looked like this:

```
                (14)

 (4 7)                   (18 25)

(1,2)(5,6)(8,10,12)    (14,16)(19,21)(26,27,32,36)
```

*the above is a correct b-tree.*

```
                  (14)

 (**94** 7)                   (18 25)

(1,2)(5,6)(8,10,12)    (14,16)(19,21)(26,27,32,36)
```

However, the above is an invalid b-tree since 94 is greater then 14.

whats the best way in Java to traverse the tree so i can find out if the nodes are in the correct order? Basically i'd like to write a function that can tell me if a tree is a valid b-tree.

update: the structure for the node looks like this:

```
class Node {
    List<Integer> keys;
    List<Node> children;
}
```

Comment: Do you have a data structure you are using for your b-tree?  If so, can you post it?

Answer (score 0):

Just use an in-order traversal and make sure it is sorted.  If this is an integrity check then you should also confirm all children have the same height and each node is at least half full.

Answer (score 0):

You can do an inorder traversal and ensure that the current element in the traversal is at least greater than the previous element.

Also regarding your golden rule, there are several authors out there who have written that the keys on the left should be **lesser than** **or equal to** and keys on the right can be **greater than** **or equal to**.